# Getting someone else's mail

Tags: bug, chat, notifications

Is this a bug? Or was it the pinging user's fault for not resolving the ambiguity?

I'm getting notified when someone in chat is attempting to @ping another user with a, shall we say, [fairly similar name](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-francois-fabre).

These notifications

[image]

were triggered in chat thusly:

[image]

Clearly, the intended recipient is my homonym, not me.

Comment: When pinging, you need to enter at least the first three characters of their username. `Jean` are the first four letters of `Jean-François Corbett`.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020

Comment: So it's the user's fault. Cool. This is a duplicate. Couldn't find it before.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's *really* the user's fault - the way things work in this case is fairly unintuitive and has plenty of room for improvement.

Comment: @Dukeling It's the user's fault for not having read and understood the entire documentation i.e. all of meta!!!